# DataGridView column issues

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I fill a `DataTable` from an SQL query, then my `DataGridView` pulls the data from that table.
`dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(t,null);`
I have 12 columns in this table. The first 4 and the last 4 are displayed properly, no matter what. But in the rows where the 5th value is null, the 6th value is "moving foward".

Normal case:

`val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10, val11, val12`

If val5 is null:

`val1, val2, val3, val4, val6, val7, val8, null, val9, val10, val11, val12`

What is the issue?

edit:
Query:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(qString))
            {
                c.Open();

                // use a SqlAdapter to execute the query
                using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10, val11, val12 FROM table WHERE %CONDITIONS%", c))
                {
                    // fill a data table
                    var t = new DataTable();
                    a.Fill(t);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(t, null);
                }
            }
```

Solution: I'm a moron. I have a `UNION` in my query which pulls the same values from another table, and the order of the values in the second part of my query was not the same.

Comment: What's the query look like ?

Comment: Updated post with the query.

Comment: Have you tried dataGridView1.DataSource=t;

Comment: Just tried it, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I'm a moron. I have a UNION in my query which pulls the same values from another table, and the order of the values in the second part of my query was not the same.